# amCharts 4 - Has anyone successfully added minor ticks to an axis?

Tags: axis, amcharts4

I have a Guage chart that is scaled from 0 to 120.  Automatically, major ticks are drawn every 10 points and there are no minor ticks.  I would like to add minor ticks that increment by 2.  Thus far I have not been able to find a way to do this.  Can anyone please provide some guidance or even better a solution?

In amCharts 3, configuring [minor ticks](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/gaugeaxis/#minorTickInterval_property) is clearly documented.  However, in amCharts 4 this feature has disappeared and a more generic method appears to be used.  However, I have not found any documentation or demo that helps to solve this simple problem.

If you want to play with code, [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-gauge/) is a great place to start.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution works.  It requires drawing a second axis and adjusting the scale  range and the spacing using minGridDistance. The results from the code below is:

[Simple gauge chart based on the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCiN1.png)

I did find that minGridDistance did not behave predictably across all scale ranges.  For a range of values from 0 to a maximum range of 120, minGridDistance did not work. However, for a maximum range of 60 (in the example below) and for 500, minGridDistance worked fine.  Thus, some experimentation is required.

```
/**
 * minor ticks
 */

var axis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
axis.min = 0;
axis.max = 60;
axis.strictMinMax = true;
axis.renderer.radius = am4core.percent(100);
axis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
axis.renderer.inside = false;
axis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
axis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
axis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
axis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 8;
axis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
axis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;


/**
 * major ticks and labels
 */
var axis2 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
axis2.min = 0;
axis2.max = 120;
axis2.strictMinMax = true;
axis2.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;
axis2.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
axis2.renderer.ticks.template.length = 13;
axis2.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
axis2.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
```